# Api Gateway change Stage name

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cdk, aws-api-gateway

How could I change Stage name in AWS API Gateway? I haven't found rename function in console and neither in CLI.

For example creating new stage with CLI:

1. `aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id ${RESTAPIID} --stage-name ''`

or

2. `aws apigateway create-stage --rest-api-id abcde123456 --stage-name ThisIsMyStageName --deployment-id abdcde`

My best guess is to use "`update-stage`" function but don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API Gateway's stage name is a ressource ID. This mean you cannot edit it.

However, you can easily create a new stage and delete the old one

Comment: For some reason my question got minus , but your answer is right. Thank you! I created a new stage with all settings from old stage(ie. Stage variables) and deleted the other with wrong name.